# Parsing a local xml file in iOS sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I need to parse a local xml file which is in my resource folder when a UIButton is pressed. I know how to parse an XML file from the web. Now how can i display the xml content which is in my resource folder.

How do I parse a local XML file?

Answer (score 43):

I assume from your tags that you're using NSXMLParser to parse the XML. In that case, you can do this:

```
NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
// do whatever you want with xmlParser
```